# In Linux: Print last line of log file that starts with

Tags: linux, logging, redhat, tail

I am trying to have the output of a single OS command display the last line of a log file, that starts with a specific string.

So basically I have a log file that reads:

```
Tom 
Paul 
Tom 
Steve 
Anthony 
Tom
```

I want to type a command similar to this:

```
tail -1 /etc/logfile | grep Steve
```

and have output like this:
Steve

Unfortunately, the output of `tail -1` only shows the last line of the log file...IF it matches.  I want it to search the log file, from the bottom to the top (most recent to oldest) and print the first entry that matches the "Starts with" or grep.  Thank you.  I tried a bunch of combinations of tail, sed, cat and less...but I may be just doing something small wrong and missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it the other way round `grep Steve /etc/logfile | tail -l`

```
grep Steve /etc/logfile
```

Gets all the lines with Steve then

```
tail -1
```

Prints the last of those.

Comment: but then how do I close the tail? and how do I specify to grep in the logfile?  I tried grep Steve | tail -1 /etc/logfile and it just returned Tom and kept the tail open.

Comment: The tail will close after the grep completes closing the pipe. I missed out the log file the first time, check my corrected answer.

Comment: So, I had a thought, and maybe I need to ask a whole new question, but could I develop a shell script to do this function, for a set list of patterns?  For example...Patterns=Steve,Tom within the script.  Then the script will go through each pattern, grep the pattern out of the log file and then tail -1 to display the last entry for it.  This way, it would display the last entry for each name I am looking for, using one script.  I know this is far more complex....would I need to ask a whole new question?

Comment: For simplicity, you could just put the separate grep/tail commands for each pattern into a file to make a script.

Answer (score 3):

If the log is small enough that you don't care to scan it entirely, then

```
grep Steve etc/logfile | tail -n 1
```

will do your job. If the file is really big, you don't want to grep it since it will impact performance, so I will suggest building a script that read the file in reverse and stops in the first occurrence.